# The Sound SE community is about to get much bigger!

Tags: discussion, avp-sound-merge

It's with a great deal of pleasure that I'm letting you all know that [your community is soon to grow quite a bit](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/merging-with-social-sound-design-and-a-surprise-ending). The linked post on Meta Audio & Video production outlines our plan to bring the audio questions and community over here to Sound SE so that video production can have a site of their own.

This is going to result in some great users and content coming over to Sound SE, along with what we hope is going to be increased, sustained participation by more engaged users. You'll have a greater number of interesting questions to answer, and more experts watching the site to answer the questions that you have.

#### What's the plan?

This is what's going to happen, in a nutshell - followed by a little bit of friendly guidance for all that are now calling Sound SE their community. Most of you won't notice anything except quite a few new posts that have answers, and new faces that seem to be established users.

The most important take away from this, if you're in a hurry is that there are no strangers here, just friends we haven't met yet. Please do your best to welcome these new additions to your community and for those that are coming over, [remember that Sound SE is an older, established site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214453/did-se-change-its-qa-format-to-just-another-internet-forum/214455#214455) with some interesting ways of going about things. There's not much currently here on meta, this is a perfect opportunity for a few new [discussion](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) topics to be raised.

I've also set up [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12614/sound-design-avp-merge-project) for project collaboration and general Q&A about what we're doing.

#### And we're off!

Below are the steps that we're going to follow to make this merge as smooth and painless as possible. I'll be crossing these off as they're completed, so this post is a handy reference for the state of things while the project is underway. I expect this to take about a week, with the bulk of migrations happening in the first few days.

- Establish cross moderation between the sites (mods on both sites have diamonds on both sites)
- Begin migrating questions that are purely, or mostly sound related to Sound SE
- Migrate any active sound related meta topics on meta AVP to meta Sound SE
- Normalize tags across everything we just imported (this may take some time and quite a few discussions)
- Begin discussions related to helping make sure everyone that loves Sound SE is happy with the new arrangements

... after that, it's onto video - folks here just need to settle into their new home and go back to the questions that they enjoy.

***Moderators of both sites, please ensure that you have linked accounts on both sites so that I can finish setting up your access in both places. This is essential in order to help the migration process go smoothly.*** (emphasis on *linked*)

If you have questions or concerns *specifically* about the merge as it progresses, please use the appropriate main tag, along with [avp-sound-merge](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avp-sound-merge), this will help us find your question quickly (remember, there's going to be meta discussion migration happening too).

I'm really excited to finally get this underway, and I hope you are too. I'm thrilled to see these two *extremely* friendly communities come together, and rest assured that you're in good hands while we complete the process of merging.

Comment: Note, there's a [related meta post](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/353/the-audio-merge-with-sound-design-se-is-now-underway) on AVP, but if you're here you're already where you need to be and just need to hang tight for everything to be moved over.